# How to fix "No resource identifier found for attribute layout_centerHorizontal in package android"?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-button, android-attributes

I get an error on the button which is annoying, and I'm confused. The problem is the button. It says no resource identifier found for attribute `layout_centerHorizontal` in package android.

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.companey.ali.Main" >
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizantal="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/alireza" />
        
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/alireza" 
        
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my `string.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <string name="app_name">Ali</string>
        <string name="alireza">Alireza</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    
    </resources>
```

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: no one will be able to answer you question because you didn't ask a one :)

Comment: where and what is the error?

Comment: You left your TextView open.

Comment: i get error on the <buttom

Comment: sorry i forgot to write it my problem is exactly on the <button it says no resource identifier found for attribute layout_centerHorizental in package android

Comment: Check your spelling! `android:layout_centerHorizantal="true"` You wrote it **twice**: once **wrong** and once correct. It stops on the wrong one, which happens to be the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You left TextView if it is that one, but you didn't ask a question ?

It should be layout_centerHorizontal  you made a typo

Comment: sorry i forgot to write it my problem is exactly on the <button it says no resource identifier found for attribute layout_centerHorizental in package android

Comment: It should be layout_centerHorizontal  you made a typo

Answer (score 0):

you need to close your TextView Tag:

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alireza"/>
```

Second problem is that you have used the same attribute twice, also you misspelled one of the duplicate ones. Both are wrong, change them ....

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/alireza" />
```

TIP: you can also use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: i did it but problem still resist.

Comment: sorry i forgot to write it my problem is exactly on the <button it says no resource identifier found for attribute layout_centerHorizental in package android

Comment: remove layout_centerHorizental... there is no such thing. It is layout_centerHorizontal .... also you can not use the same attribute twice in one widget...

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two same lines in one Button, you just delete one.

```
android:layout_centerHorizantal="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

And TextView must be close with `/>`